# Cannot read property 'style' of null`, but works fine in jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a very basic game in with JS, my code works fine(ish) in jsfiddle, it doesnt work when im putting it all into my HTML and JS documents however - i keep getting the same error when debugging: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null` at line 11 stating `bigThing.style.left = "10px";`

First noobie question here, hope anybody can help me figure out why it doesn't work to just copy-paste this into an html document.

[JsFiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/qw7rjvgx/4/)`

Thank you for your time.

Comment: In the Fiddle your JS is placed in the body. What about your actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the entire thing inside of a:

```
window.onload = function(){
   //You code here
}
```

The problem can arise when you have your script loading and executing prior to the DOM being parsed.  One other alternative is to place your scripts immediately prior to the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: ... unless it's at the end of the body

Comment: I was debating on adding that, but personally dislike that approach.  Regardless, bump and added to answer.

Comment: That did it! I can't believe it was that simple, thanks a ton.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is quite straight forward. Your HTML file is parsed top-down as it is an interpreted script. I am going to assume you import your JS script inside your head tags. The JS is trying to access the DOM before it is fully loaded, this causes the error to be thrown. Make it so your JS script import is called after all of the content in the body of your HTML file. Your markup will load, then JS will access it, and all should be good.

Comment: This seems more like an explanation than an answer